# How to get listboxitem?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have a `ListBox`. If I use `listBox.Items[0]` I get this item datacontent, but I want to get this item's height.

How to get this information?

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `VisualTreeHelper` [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
You can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521980/list-box-and-visual-tree-helper). So, if you need just first element - use it in this way:

```
        var item = FindFirstElementInVisualTree<ListBoxItem>(listBox);
        var height = item != null ? item.ActualHeight : 0.0;
```

If you need to check not only the first one, feel free to modify that method or write you own.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But I use DataTemplate for my listboxitem, I can't get any listboxitem by using FindFirstElementInVisualTree...why?